# txt[0], txt[1] = txt[1], txt[0] AND a, b = 1,2 a,b = b,a

Tags: python

```
txt = "hello"
txt[0], txt[1] = txt[1], txt[0]
```

why doesn't this code work?

Isn't it similar to this?

```
a, b = 1,2
a,b = b,a
```

Comment: My answer would be that [strings are immutable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_string_immutability.htm).

Comment: Strings in python are immutable

Comment: that would work if you used lists, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, strings do not support the syntax `str[num] = ...` at all. The problem is not that you are trying to swap values, it is just that strings cannot be edited like that at all.